# Is there any standards to get a nested objects in restful web service?

Tags: json, rest, web-services

I want to implement a method to get a nested objects (40 nested Object JSON format) and apply some businesses on objects, then insert those in some tables.

Is a good way to get all data objects in one web service method, or write some separate web service methods to get data and break input nested objects?

Is there any standards to implement web service?

Can any one introduce any books or articles to explain standards of web service implementation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to decide yourself whether the infrastructure (e.g. network connection, server capacity) can handle the "large" dataset and whether it is useful for your consuming clients to receive all of the datasets (they might need only a part of it most of the time).

If say 80% percent of the time it's a subset, you can return that subset and the rest of it you can use [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS).

Those are just links where the client can direct themselves to if they need data which was not sent in the initial call to your API.

Comment: my dataset is not large, it's a bit large, for example 40 nested objects, there is no limit in network or server